# Normalising data - bulk inserts using loop

Tags: ms-access, vba, bulkinsert

Does anyone have any tips that could help speed up a process of breaking down a table and inserting a large number of records into a new table.

I'm currently using Access and VBA to convert a table that contains records with a large string (700 + characters) into a new table where each character has its own record (row). I'm doing this by looping through the string 1 character at a time and inserting into the new table using simple DAO in VBA.

Currently I'm working with a small subset of data - 300 records each with a 700 character string. This process takes about 3 hours to run so isn't going to scale up to the full dataset of 50,000 records!

table 1 structure

id - string
001 - abcdefg

becomes

table 2 structure

id - string
001 - a
001 - b
001 - c
.   .
.   .
.   .

I'm open to any suggestions that could improve things.

Cheers

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example using Northwind. Create a table called Sequence with an `INTEGER` (Access = Long Integer) and populate it with values 1 to 20 (i.e. 20 row table). Then use this ACE/Jet syntax SQL code to parse each letter of the employees' last names:

```
SELECT E1.EmployeeID, E1.LastName, S1.seq, MID(E1.LastName, S1.Seq, 1)
  FROM Employees AS E1, Sequence AS S1
 WHERE S1.seq BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(E1.LastName);
```

Comment: Thats a really good solution! would never have thought of that!

Would it be possible to insert a date via sql thats incremented by 1 for each record?

Comment: That is a lot of dates!

INSERT INTO Table2 (TextString, RecDate) SELECT "STR " & s.Seq & " " &  Mid(Field2,s.Seq,1) AS t,
Date()+s.Seq AS d
FROM Table1, Sequence AS s
WHERE s.Seq Between 1 And 700

Comment: Cheers guys!

For reference I ended up with

SELECT E1.STUD_ID, Mid(E1.marks,S1.Seq,1) AS Mark, Abs(-1+(S1.Seq Mod 2)) AS Period,dateadd("d",int(([S1].[Seq]-1)/2),E1.marksstart_date) AS Mdate
FROM Final_Lac_2007 AS E1, Sequence2 AS S1
WHERE (((S1.seq) Between 1 And Len([E1].[marks])));

As I needed to increment the date every other number as Im working with attendance data which has two sessions a day.

gone from >3 hours to < 10 secs :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing bulk inserts, you can often get a substantial performance boost by dropping the table's indexes, doing the bulk insert, and then restoring the indexes.  In one case, when inserting a couple million records into a MySQL table, I've seen this bring the run time down from 17 hours to about 20 minutes.

I can't advise specifically regarding Access (I haven't used it since Access 2, 15 or so years ago), but the general technique is applicable to pretty much any database engine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, the tables currently have no indexes, think the performance issue is down to having to run an individual insert statement for every record.

Answer (score 0):

We have a routine that transposes data. Not sure if the code is optimized, but it runs significantly faster after the file has been compacted.

Doing a lot of deleting and rebuilding of tables bloats an .mdb file significantly.